# PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "172.17.0.1", user "XXX", database "XXX", SSL off ):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, digital-ocean

I am using `postgres:9.4.5` image for my project using `dockers` on `digitalocean` droplet.

Following is the `docker-compose.yml` configurations for `postgres`.

```
db:

  # use the preferred version of the official Postgres image
  # see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
  build: .
  # build with a different Dockerfile
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-pg

  # persist the database between containers by storing it in a volume
  volumes:
    - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: XXX
```

Inside `Dockerfile-pg` i have following configurations

```
FROM postgres:9.4.5

EXPOSE 5432
```

When, I `build` and run images I get the following `error`

```
PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "172.17.0.1", user "XXX", database "XXX", SSL off ):
```

I already set the following line to allow all connections in `postgresql.conf` file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

inside `pg_hba.conf` file I also set up following line to allow for all connections

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

I also set the `local` environment with the same `configurations` on my local system. Everything is working fine on my local machine. Everything was also working fine on server on `digitalocean` few days back.

I don't know why it is trying to connect with this IP `172.17.0.1`. I have set up  `HOST_IP` for `postgres` which is my `droplet ip`.

I don't know why I am getting this `error`. I tried everything to fix it.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you restart the database?

Comment: No, for deployment i used normal docker-compose commands to "build" and "up" docker images

Comment: I restarted database, but still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Check you `pg_hba.conf` file.
You might have options that you haven't added such as

```sh
host all pgdbadm 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

This pgdbadm is known for account created by crypto-mining hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Add **?ssl=true&sslmode=require** to your datasourse.url. E.g.

```
url: ${db.url:jdbc:postgresql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:5432}/${db.name:my_db}}?ssl=true&sslmode=require
```